# Display the number of item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to count the number of comment on my page called view

here is my controler code

```
  def view
    @gallery = Gallery.find_by!(id: params[:id]).decorate
    @comments = Comment.select(:user_id, :description).includes(:user).where(gallery_id: @gallery.id)
    if user_signed_in?
      @like = current_user.likes.where(gallery_id: @gallery.id).first
    end
  end
```

this is view page

```
  .text-container
    p: strong Komentar
    - @comments.each do |comment|
      .media.testimoni-box
        .col-md-12.jaminan
          .media-heading.strong = comment.user_personal_name
          = comment.description
          - # want to show the number of comment here
```

Please help me. and thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

you can loop the `@comments` collection `with_index` and use that as counter

```
.text-container
  p: strong Komentar
  - @comments.each.with_index(1) do |comment, count|
    .media.testimoni-box
      .col-md-12.jaminan
        .media-heading.strong = comment.user_personal_name
        = comment.description
        = count
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. its work when i put below =comment.descrption. but how if i put outside the .text-container? i mean the total of comment

Comment: @LukniBurhanuddinAhmad `@comments.count` to get the total

Comment: like @Andrei said .. just addd `= @comments.count` nested to `.text-container`

Comment: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' description) FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`gallery_id` = 18' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(user_id, description) FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`gallery_id` = 18

Comment: that's the error from your activerecord orm query run to get `@comments` .. test that query in your rails console if it is returning a list or not